# Função no next.js não retorna os dados recebidos da API. Como solucionar?

Tags: typescript, next.js

Minha function signInRequest não retorna os dados recebidos da API, alguma solução? Sendo que no postman a mesma requisição na API retorna os dados, e nessa chamada do ApiService.post retorno os dados, mas a função não expõe.

Segue os códigos.

**auth.ts**

```
export async function signInRequest(data:LoginRequest) {
    let token = "";
    let user = null;
    ApiService.post('/auth/signin', {
        "username": data.username,
        "password": data.password
    }).then((result) => {
        token = result.data.token;
        user = result.data;
    });
    return {
        token,
        user
    }
}
```

Então faço a chamada no meu provider custom.

**AuthProvider.tsx**

```
export function AuthProvider({ children } : any) {
    const [ user, setUser ] = useState<Usuario|null>(null);
    const isAuthenticated = !!user;

    useEffect(() => {
        const { 'nextauth.token': token } = parseCookies();

        if(token) {
            recoverUserInfo().then(response => setUser(response.user));
        }
    }, []);

    async function signIn(data: LoginRequest) {
        const { token, user } = await signInRequest(data); //Chamado aqui a função acima da api
        
        //Nesse ponto não chega
        setCookie(undefined, 'nextauth-token', token, {
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24, //1 dia
        });

        setUser(user);

        Router.push("/");
    }

    
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{user, isAuthenticated, signIn}}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Que também chama no onClick do botão da minha página de login.

**login.tsx**

```
    const { signIn } = useContext(AuthContext);

    const [ username, setUsername ] = useState("");
    const [ password, setPassword ] = useState("");

    async function handleSignIn() {
      await signIn({username: username, password: password});
    }
```

Alguma sugestão do que pode estar ocorrendo, haja visto que sou iniciante em next.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema que você está enfrentando está relacionado à natureza assíncrona das chamadas API e ao uso de `await` na função `signInRequest`.

No seu código, a função `signInRequest` é assíncrona e faz uma chamada à API usando `ApiService.post`, que também é assíncrona. No entanto, a função não aguarda a resposta da API antes de retornar os valores. Isso ocorre porque o `await` está sendo usado apenas dentro do `then` da chamada `ApiService.post`, e não está esperando a resolução da promessa antes de retornar.

Para resolver esse problema, você precisa transformar a função `signInRequest` em uma função assíncrona e usar o `await` corretamente. Veja a modificação no código:

```js
export async function signInRequest(data: LoginRequest) {
    try {
        const result = await ApiService.post('/auth/signin', {
            "username": data.username,
            "password": data.password
        });

        const token = result.data.token;
        const user = result.data;

        return {
            token,
            user
        };
    } catch (error) {
        // Lide com erros aqui, se necessário
        console.error('Erro na requisição de signIn:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Ao tornar a função `signInRequest` assíncrona e usar `await`, você garante que ela aguarde a resposta da API antes de retornar os dados. Dessa forma, quando você chamar `await signInRequest(data)` no `AuthProvider.tsx`, o código aguardará a resolução da promessa e obterá os valores corretos.

Com essa alteração, a sua função `signIn` dentro do `AuthProvider.tsx` deve receber os dados corretos da API, e o restante do seu código deve funcionar conforme esperado. Certifique-se de lidar com erros adequadamente dentro da função `signInRequest` e tratar exceções, caso ocorram.

Recomendo também verificar a documentação do `ApiService.post` para garantir que ele lida corretamente com chamadas assíncronas e promessas para garantir a integridade das respostas da API.